# How to use `dotnet format` to apply specific StyleCop rule globally?

Tags: c#, stylecop, dotnet-cli, dotnet-format

I have installed `StyleCop.Analyzers` on my project that is written using `C#`. The rules severity are set to `suggestion`.

How can I apply specific rules on the entire project using `dotnet format`?

I tried executing `dotnet format SolutionName.sln --diagnostics SA1122` to convert all `""` to `string.Empty`. Many files were updated (file timestamp changed), but none of the `""` were replaced by `string.Empty` as expected.

How can I use `dotnet format` to apply specific format rule globally so I don't have to manually make the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe an issue in the CLI command. It works when used with other arguments like `--severity info`

```
dotnet format SolutionName.sln --severity info --diagnostics SA1122
```